# Extract Text from Array - perl

Tags: arrays, perl, text, extract

I am trying to extract the Interface from an array created from an SNMP Query.

I want to create an array like THIS:

```
my @array = ( "Gig 11/8",
              "Gig 10/1",
              "Gig 10/4",
              "Gig 10/2");
```

It currently looks like THIS:

```
my @array = 
( "orem-g13ap-01    Gig 11/8          166            T       AIR-LAP11 Gig 0",
  "orem-g15ap-06    Gig 10/1          127            T       AIR-LAP11 Gig 0",
  "orem-g15ap-05    Gig 10/4          168            T       AIR-LAP11 Gig 0",
  "orem-g13ap-03    Gig 10/2          132            T       AIR-LAP11 Gig 0");>
```

I am doing THIS:

```
foreach $ints (@array) {
         @gig = substr("$ints", 17, 9);
         print("Interface: @gig");
```

Sure it works, but the hostname [orem-g15ap-01] doesn't always stay the same length, it varies depending on the site. I need to extract the word "Gig" plus the next 6 characters. I have no idea what is the best way of doing this.

I am a novice at perl but trying. Thanks

Comment: Look up "regular expressions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# "I need to extract the word "Gig" plus the next 6 characters."
# This looks like a fixed-with file format, so consider using unpack.
foreach ( @lines ) {
    my( $orem, $gig, $rest ) = unpack 'a17 a9 a*';
    print "[$gig]\n";
}
```

If it's not fixed-with format, then you need to find out what the file spec is and then maybe use a regular expression, something like:

```
    my( $orem, $gig, $rest ) = m/(\S+)\s+(.{9})(.*)/;
```

But this will not work in the general case without a proper file spec.

Comment: Without the unnecessary work (method 1): `my $gig = unpack 'x17 a9';`

Comment: Without the unnecessary work (method 2): `my ($gig) = /^\S+\s+(\S+\s+\S+)/s;`

Comment: I cannot believe how quick and accurate the responses are! This is my first time on this site. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like that is what Perl is made for. Regular Expressions are the way to go. Read the [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

```
foreach $ints (@array) {
  $ints =~ s/(Gig.{6})/$1/g;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll Read that, I am somewhat a noob, now everyone is telling me to use Python, and that confuses me even more.

Comment: Oh, Python is nice. Perl is nice too. Each language has its own merits.

Answer (score 1):

So you want the second and third field.

```
my @array = map { /^\S+\s+(\S+\s\S+)/s } @source;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is like ikegami's, but I recommend that if you know how something you want looks, then by all means, specify *that*. Because this is done in a list context, any string that does not match the spec, returns an empty list--or is ignored.

```
my @results = map { m!(\bGig\s+\d+/d+)! } @array;
```